# Get PATH instead of URL

Tags: php

This code:

```
$files[$file->ID]['file_title'] = '<p><a target="_blank" href="' . esc_url( wp_get_attachment_url( $file->ID ) ) . '">' . $real_title . '</a>' . $title . '</p>';
```

Gives me:

```
https://example.com/wp-content/uploads/2022/03/sample.pdf`
```

But I want:

```
/wp-content/uploads/2022/03/sample.pdf`
```

How do I remove `https://example.com/`?

Answer (score 1):

You can use [parse_url](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.parse-url.php) to get the path information from a URL:

```
parse_url(wp_get_attachment_url($file->ID) , PHP_URL_PATH)
```

https://3v4l.org/5KmsJ

Alternatively `str_replace` or `preg_replace` could be used to remove `https://example.com/` that those can result in incorrect results.

Comment: Thank you so much! I am just curious, is it also possible to remove `/wp-content/`?

Comment: You would need to use `str_replace` for that. Example, https://3v4l.org/GdKAj